# How to get values from text fields and use them in another class?

Tags: java, swing

I have a GUI that allows a user to enter their personal information. I want to get all that information and use it in another class to create an instance of that person. I keep getting

> non-static method getValues(String, String...) cannot be referenced from a static context

even though none of my methods are static.

I have tried to use individual getters for each text field, but that gave the same error. I also tried to get each value through one method and then call it in the other class but that doesn't work either.

In this class I am trying to get the values from the GUI:

```
public class PatientStrategy implements IAccountStrategy {

@Override
public void createAccount(String accountType, String firstname, String lastname,
          String address, String postcode, String sex, Integer age){
    PMSGUI.getValues(accountType, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, sex, age);
}
```

And this is the method I'm using in the GUI itself to get the values from the text fields:

```
public class PMSGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public void getValues(String accountType, String firstname, String lastname, String address,
                      String postcode, String sex, Integer age) {
    accountType = cboAccountType.getSelectedItem().toString();
    firstname = txtFirstName.getText();
    lastname = txtLastName.getText();
    address = txtAddress.getText();
    postcode = txtPostcode.getText();
    sex = cboSex.getSelectedItem().toString();
    age = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText());
}
```

I am using an observer and strategy pattern and so I will be taking the values from the GUI and will be creating a new instance of each person as an observer.

I'm new to programming in Java and so I know I'm probably going about this all wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Using `PMSGUI.getValues` is exactly where you are trying to access a non-static method in a static context. To access a method, you have to create an *instance* and use the method with that *instance*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by create an instance of the method exactly?

Comment: Create an instance of the *class*, not of the method. Use `new PMSGUI()` somewhere. I'm sure you already have an instance or the GUI would not be shown.

Comment: Oh I see. Would creating a new instance of the GUI reset all the values in the text field then, or does it create an instance while keeping the inputted values? Sorry if I'm looking at this the wrong way.

Comment: You are supposed to use the same instance that you are using already, otherwise you'll have two GUIs appear.

Comment: And by the way, Your method will not return the values anyway. You cannot change the values of the parameters in order to return them! Only the return value of the method is passed back to the caller. You should probably start with some Java Basics.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, I'll take a look

Comment: I think it would be better to pass the properties from the GUI to the strategy instead

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that `getValues()`, a non-static method, needs a non-static context. This context is provided by any instance of the defining class. An instantiation is a construction from a "static" class into a "dynamic" object (this object may only exist, while your program is running). Since one class can have many such objects, created from one class, each of them is called an *instance*.

Now if there should be at most one such window at a time, then you can apply the [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to your GUI class. Then you would be able to access all non-static methods through the provided static instance of the class.

```
public class PMSGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static final PMSGUI instance = new PMSGUI();

    private PMSGUI() {} // Restrict instantiation

    public static PMSGUI getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    // Add your custom methods further down here
}
```

Now to reference it in your calling method, use

```
PMSGUI.getInstance().getValues(accountType, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, sex, age);
```